# How to display the Binary Logging Log in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Binary Logging is turned on. The log file, device-bin.index, is present. 
When I click Server/Server Logs I get tabs for Error Log File, General Log File, and Slow log File. I don't get a tab for the Binary Log. 
MySQLWorkbench version 6.3, MySQL Server Version 5.7.18

[image: MySQLWorkbench]

[image]

Comment: Try this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html

Comment: @vipin I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: have you checked that binary logging is enabled

Comment: @vipin you're obviously not reading my question. I posted proof the binary logging is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench has no support for the binary log in the log viewer. Only what is of common interest is there.

Answer (score 2):

For MYSQL Workbench 8.0 you can access the logs in the Help menu -> Locate log files.